# Error while trying to install Python module on local machine

Tags: python, linux, permissions

I am trying to install Python module on my machine. While installing, there is an error on terminal.

It was OK until this step:

> Writing
>   /usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/athletelist-1.0.0.egg-info

Then it shows an error:

> error: /usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/athletelist-1.0.0.egg-info: Permission denied

Why? How to solve this problem?

PS. I use Ubuntu 11.04 and I am quiet new on Linux World.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The important part is **Permission denied**: You just don't have the right to write to system folders.

The simplest fix is to prefix the failing command with `sudo`, that is with root/administrator privileges.

In the long run you should learn about Unix permissions.

Another way would be to install the package in your home directory but that may not be an option depending on your plans for the new package.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes..I should learn about Unix.